# Propose suitable algorithm for min-max optimization problem

Tags: optimization

Consider:

\begin{equation}\min_{x, y} \max_{\omega} | f(x, y, \omega) |\end{equation}

where $(x , y)\in  \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} $ and $\omega \in (0, \infty)$.

$f$ is the result of dividing two polynomials. In exact details we have :

\begin{equation} f = \frac{cz+d}{z^m(z^2+az+b)+cz+d} \end{equation}

where $ z = e^{j\omega} $. $a , b, m$ are constant numbers and $c,d$ depend on $x, y$

The optimization process begin with initial condition $(x_0, y_0)$, and the aim is to get optimal value in **least** iteration in the neighbor of $(x_0, y_0)$ with radius $r$.

What is suitable algorithm for this MiniMax (MiMa) problem?

Comment: a lot will depend on the properties of the function $f$ itself. can you specify a bit more about it?

Comment: @dexter04 Thanks for your comment. I added more details in question.

Comment: Have you tried to find its analytical solution? By finding partial derviatives w.r.t $x,y,\omega$